# Sphinx search engine creates error in example code

Tags: full-text-search, python-sphinx

I am working with documentation built with Sphinx. I created a code example:

```
    {
      "speechModel" : {
            "language": "en-UK",
            "features" : [  "advancedPunctuation"  ]
      }
    }
```

[image]
However if I do a search and enter "advanced punctuation" in the filter, it displays as in the screenshot above, which would be misleading to a user. If I copy and paste what looks like "advanced Punctuation", it will render correctly, in camelCase without the space. But it's still problematic that it appears incorrectly.

Has anyone discovered a solution to this search issue with Sphinx?

Comment: My guess is that the JavaScript search highlighter function splits the value into what it considers words, and applies a style to each word that has left and right padding. Try using your browser's developer tools to isolate where this happens, then customize your theme's CSS or whatever applies the styles.

Comment: I'm using Sphinx 3.5.2 & Alabaster 0.7.12 and I can't replicate your problem so far.  (The search for "advanced punctuation" doesn't return any results.)  I suspect Steve is on the right track, but it might be easier to provide a bit more help if you can update your question with the theme and Sphinx version you are using.